# Python module install, setting up the 'environment' for a specific module

Tags: python, graph, path, plot, installation

Trying to install a Python module called Dislin. Unfortunately I haven't had success setting the environment for Dislin, and I will get an install error. The instructions for setting the path are below, but they are a bit obscure to me. Can anyone make it a bit more explicit? (I'm learning).

```
d) Choose a directory in the file structure where DISLIN should be
   installed and define the environment variable DISLIN with it:

   For example:   export DISLIN/$HOME/dislin
```

ftp://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/grafik/dislin/darwin/README.DARWIN

My site packages for python 2.7 are here: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages. I would assume I need to point Dislin home here, but so far have not been successful, as I am probably doing it wrong, but I get an error like: export: `DISLIN/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dislin': not a valid identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already installed dislin, what you have to do is make sure that wherever you've installed the data for *dislin* (not for Python), is on your system environmental variable [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).  This is pointed out in **#5** in the ftp link you posted.

What you would do, if dislin can be found on your computer at the path you posted above, is add the following to your PYTHONPATH:

```
DISLIN/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dislin
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually it requires that the environment is set prior to install.

Comment: You can set up your PYTHONPATH Prior to install also.  That's purely a system thing.

Comment: I tried export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:DISLIN/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dislin, I guess that is not quite right, as I still get an install error.

Comment: Installing dislin in: /home/dislin/python and setting the PYTHONPATH as seen in this echo worked for me: echo $PYTHONPATH :/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg:/Users/home/dislin/python